# How do I determine if a Xamarin Forms application is running from the FirebaseMessagingServie's OnMessageRecieved?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have an application written using **Xamarin.Forms** that implements **Push Notifications** using the `FirebaseMessagingService`.  If my app is running when the message is received I want to change an icon, which is bound to the static `boolean` variable `Info.Messages`

```cs
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{
    **Info.Messages = true;**
    // Code that handles the notification ..
}
```

When the app is running in either the foreground or background this works great.  When the app is not running, it throws the exception:

> CustomFirebaseMessagingService OnMessageRecieved Exception: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.

`Info` is a type so I can't check for it's existence before I set it.  `Info.Messages` is a `boolean` so it is never `null`, if I check it's value I get false.  What can I check to avoid the exception?

Comment: I used dependenceService to acheve it(But I do not change the icon). When I colse my Application. I cannot got the exception when I close my application. Please open your MainActivity.cs, check If you have `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` in the `OnCreate` method.Please follow this thread to check the `init()` postion:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54547719/10627299

Comment: I do init forms in my main activity, that is not my issue.  My issue is I need to determine that the app is not running (and forms is not initted) so I don't try to set the variable that is not valid/needed in that situation.

Comment: Do you want to check other application that used `FirebaseMessagingService`? If so, you can use  `ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);` in the android platform.